# Waves in $2$ different mediums - Why do we do it like this?

Tags: waves, continuum-mechanics

When we were solving the wave equations in the case of $2$ different mediums, we were assuming that, when a longitudinal wave reaches the border, there will be 1 reflected longitudinal and 1 reflected transversal, and there will also be 1-1 transent wave. But, in the case of the initial wave is transversal, we were assuming only transversal waves. Why did we do it this way?

The equation is:
$$\frac{\partial^2 \vec{u}}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \bigtriangleup \vec{u}$$

Comment: Can you explain where you find this and what kind of waves you mean?

Comment: @my2cts It's from a class. Specifically, waves in continuum mechanics.